# Equational identities of the $(+,*,0,1)$ reducts of rings

Tags: universal-algebra

This is a follow up to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4094385/7062) on the equational identities of the $(+,*,0,1)$ reducts of commutative rings. In this question, I want to consider the equational identities of the $(+,*,0,1)$ reducts of rings, not necessarily commutative. I conjecture that

1. $x+0=x$
2. $x+y=y+x$
3. $(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$
4. $x*1=x$
5. $1*x=x$
6. $(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)$
7. $x*(y+z)=(x*y)+(x*z)$
8. $(x+y)*z=(x*z)+(y*z)$
9. $x*0=0$
10. $0*x=0$

is a sufficient finite basis. Is this true?

Comment: In addition to providing the link to your previous question (I edited to add it), you should at least indicate that you tried to adapt the answer given by Keith Kearnes to the case of non-commutative rings. At what point does the argument break down?

Comment: Axioms $1$ to $10$ are exactly the axioms of a semiring. So, you want to show that the subvariety of semirings generated by the rings contains all semirings?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I didn't adapt the answer from Keith Kearnes. To be honest, I didn't even understand his argument on my previous question.

Comment: @user107952 then why did you accept it?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Because it "looked" correct. Honestly, sometimes I don't understand the answers to some of my questions, but I accept it, because I can tell it seems to answer the question.